# Are there currently problems with the 'Announcer' badge?

Tags: bug, badges

Nine hours ago I got the ['Announcer' badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer) ("Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses...") for following question:
[How do I detect when the iPhone goes into landscape mode via JavaScript? Is there an event for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850472).

But

- this question is not mine
- there is and was no link in the question
- there is no comment (with question from me)
- I haven't edited the question

(Also see [the revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/850472/revisions).)

Can somebody explain me why I got the badge or is there currently a bug with this badge?

Comment: If you share the link to the question, the number of visits is tracked by the last number in the link. If I click the share button on this question, I get this: `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225384/209357`. The last number is my userid, which is used for tracking purposes. If anyone clicks on that link, it will be counted towards the badge progress.

Comment: That means I have (or someone else, I can't remember) shared a link to the question with my user id, and this link has been clicked 25 times? Then post your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: You might have shared this link long back on some site or blog..

Comment: @scessor - No need to post an answer when the duplicate question is found.